# What is the difference between "my game has just crashed" and "my game crashed"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, difference

If I want to say that my game crashed in this instant could I use both sentences below?

> 1 my game has just crashed
>
> 2 my game crashed

If not, then what is the difference between 1 and 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking to someone and your game has crashed in just that instant then you may say either 1 or 2.

However, you may **also** use 2 to describe your game crashing at any point in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Both work the same, but option 2 sounds much more natural. Option 1 makes you sound like a robot, so I would recommend avoiding it.

(This response is specific to American dialect, so it may or may not apply to you.)